# MySQL autoincrement problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with autoincrement field, I have for example 1,2,3 values, when I insert 4 and delete it the next will normally be 5. I delete 5 and after a long time , say 1 week when I insert new record the next is again 4.

Can somebody tell me why this happen , why when I insert a new record after a long time its getting the last inserted id of this table, and it is not taking into consideration the deleted records.

PS: This happens just after a long time,it is working ok when I am doing it in a short period of time

Comment: Any CRON task running over your table ?

Comment: I didn't started any cron myself, but this is on the paid hosting, so it is possible that they make some adjustments?

Comment: Is it possible that the database is being backed up / restored at any point, perhaps with missing or out-dated AUTO_INCREMENT values?  Alternatively, is the AUTO_INCREMENT column part of a multiple-column index?  See [Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html) - specifically, the part about multiple-column indexes.

Comment: About backup I thought it first time but this time I didn't made any backup, thanks for second idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last auto increment value for a table column is only stored in memory. It's not written to a table or something else. So if you restart your server (i.e. for a backup) the last increment value (5) is lost and mysql scans the table for the the last value which exists in the table (4).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't believe it and tested on localhost, and it is like this , thanks, but is there a solution for this problem to keep deleted ids after restarting the server?

Comment: I think a combination of mysql trigger, stored procedure and a table for the last id could be a solution. So that you build your own ai functionality. But I newer done this with mysql before.

Comment: ok, for those who wil met this issue, this is the problem of just InnoDB tables, so my simplest solution was to make a new field deleted, but this way you should go through all application and change stuff, other solutions could be some of shod, thanks again problem solved.
By the way there is no solution for making some adjustments to the field or table itself yet, as i read documentation.